# Multithreading and Grand Central Dispatch on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, ipad, objective-c-blocks

now i am trying to understand the concept of gcd. using grand central dispatch how to implement multithreading in my application.i have the idea about the gcd concept but i cant implement the concept to my application.i need a simple example with blocks to understand the multithreading using gcd.please help me...

Comment: The 2010 WWDC featured a very nice introductory session to both GCD and blocks after they were first introduced. The session was called [*Introducing Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch on iPhone*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).

Answer (score 18):

Ok.. The most simple example )

You can write this code in any method. For example

```
  -(void) viewDidLoad {   
     [super viewDidLoad];  
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
       //Here your non-main thread.
       NSLog (@"Hi, I'm new thread");
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //Here you returns to main thread.
       NSLog (@"Hi, I'm main thread");
       });
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its very clear and easy - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch