# How to calculate the height of a NSAttributedString without freezing the main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I'm working on an app that displays posts containing text of varying lengths. When I get data via a server request I apply formatting to a NSAttributedString, calculate the height of the text for a certain width, and then store that value for when the tableView calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` later.

For each new post that comes in I call this method:

```
- (CGFloat)calculateTextViewHeight:(NSString *)string
{
    NSAttributedString *bodyText = [self formatString:string];
    UITextView *tempTextField = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    tempTextField.attributedText = bodyText;
    return [tempTextField sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(cellWidth, FLT_MAX)].height;
}
```

This works great. However, when I loop over 50 to 200 posts at a time the tableView freezes up. From my understanding `sizeThatFits:` its a UIKit method and therefore must be executed on the main thread.

Is there a way to calculate the height of a NSAttributedString without hanging up the main thread. Or maybe is there a way to run `sizeThatFits:` on a background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you don't need to create a temp text field?

```
- (CGFloat)calculateTextViewHeight:(NSString *)string
{
  NSAttributedString *bodyText = [self formatString:string];
  CGRect rect = [bodyText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading context:nil];
  return CGRectGetHeight(rect);
}
```

Adjust the option parameters to suit your needs,

*NB: this was coded in the browser*

Comment: I have found that this technique is not as reliable as Shawn's at producing accurate numbers.

Comment: Wow, such an improvement! I haven't thoroughly tested the accuracy but its appears to be working for me. I was using a UITextView because in my custom TableViewCell I'm using a UITextView so I can easily track touches. If I use a UILabel, it works like a charm. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Better yet, the docs say that you can call NSAttributedString's methods from a background thread (as long as you don't try to share NSStringDrawingContext objects between threads.)

Comment: just create the UItextView once as an instance variable.  Then always used that to do the sizeThatFit: calc.

Comment: @DuncanC I'm quite new to Objective-C, do you know of any resources that could get me familiar with getting things on a background thread?

Comment: @ShawnThroop try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199342/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios

Comment: @DuncanC what do you mean saying "the docs say that you can call NSAttributedString's methods from a background thread"?

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html

this page says "The methods described in this class extension must be used from your app’s main thread."